# Nightwatch using chromedriver version 83 returns `undefined` global values on script

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

Hi to all and this is the first time I'm posting at StackOverflow.

My nightwatch script with a chromedriver version 77 was working before until I've updated to version 83 which throws a string value of `undefined` from the global variables at `nightwatch.conf.js` when I used it on my test script.

Here is my `nightwatch.conf.js` customized environment settings sample configuration;

```
    "dev" : {
      "product_url" : "https://website.sampledev.com",
      "demo_site" : "fake.site.com",
      "globals" : {
        "email": "demo@email.com",
        "password": "FAKEP@ssw0rd"       
      }
    },
```

**Code used:**
`var test_site = browser.demo_site`

Inputting the `demo_site` global variable to the text box of a website.
Which I used `` browser.setValue(`<sample_xpath_here>`,`${test_site}`) ``

**Expected Result:**
Inside the text box `fake.site.com`

**Actual Result:**
Inside the text box `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're missing two parts:

This line:

```js
var test_site = browser.demo_site
```

should become this instead:

```js
var test_site = browser.globals.demo_site
```

And `demo_site` should be inside `globals`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @pavelsaman. I was thinking of `globals` and `demo_site` is on the same level. Will try on this part.

Comment: Sure, let me know then. I've tried with your example on my side, so it should work with the changed line. If it works for you, you can then mark the answer as a solution for your question.

Comment: It worked on moving the `demo_site` inside the `globals` which was weird.

"globals" : {
        "demo_site" : "fake.site.com",
       }

Comment: Actually, that's correct like this. I overlooked that in my amswers, although I already tried it with `demo_site` inside `globals`. I think this is the way it's meant to be used.